# Сложение значений одинаковых ключей

Tags: java, map

Есть значение (Double) и ключ (String).

Возможно ли записывать в `map` ключи и значения, чтобы при записи повторного ключа, значение не перезаписывалось, а добавлялось к предыдущему.

Пример записи в `map`:

```
Человек 2.5
Собака 1.5
Кошка 1.5
Человек 1.5
```

`map`:

```
Человек 4
Собака 1.5
Кошка 1.5
```

Comment: Можно. достаёте значение которое уже есть, суммируете с новым и добавляете обратно. Если хотите что бы это было автоматом, то создавайте свой класс, наследуйтесь от Map и делайте.

Comment: Отнаследуйтесь от Map и реализуйте свою логику. Или сделайте класс с Map и методами с логикой, которые вам нужны

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод `merge()`:

```
        BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> bFunc = (oldValue, newValue)->oldValue+newValue;
        Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.merge("Human", 2.5, bFunc);
        map.merge("Dog", 1.5, bFunc);
        map.merge("Cat", 1.5, bFunc);
        map.merge("Human", 1.5, bFunc);
```

Comment: Класс, то что нужно! Спасибо!

Comment: можно использовать [`Double::sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#sum-double-double-) вместо своей лямбды